# Convert hex into a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript, hex

I am converting a string in VBScript Classic ASP into hex like the following:

```vb
Function StringToHex(ByRef pstrString)
    Dim llngIndex
    Dim llngMaxIndex
    Dim lstrHex
    llngMaxIndex = Len(pstrString)
    For llngIndex = 1 To llngMaxIndex
        lstrHex = lstrHex & Right("0" & Hex(Asc(Mid(pstrString, llngIndex, 1))), 2)
    Next
    StringToHex = lstrHex
End Function
```

When I pass a string for example "`moe`", I get "`6D6F65`"

Now I am trying to convert this hex back to string using stored procedure in SQL Server like the following:

```
convert(nvarchar, convert(varbinary, @Param,2))
```

but it is getting converted to the wrong string in Chinese.

Comment: Are you sure it's an `nvarchar` and not a `varchar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is a `varchar` not an `nvarchar`. Convert to the correct data type for the correct value:

```
convert(varchar, convert(varbinary, @Param,2))
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=36549a9a0d95d8014eab39b6125b2c61)

Comment: Oh silly me! I overlooked the convert part in sql and focused on vbscript! Worked like magic!  Thanks